# Stop & Wait, Go-Back-N and data link layer?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, udp, ip

I'm currently taking an introduction to computers networking course, and find it difficult to refer terms,protocols, and in general "what is the main goal of this layer" to each layer in the OSI model.

i started reading the book "Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach (6th Edition)" [James F. Kurose, Keith W. Ross], and after reading about the Application,Transport and Network layers, there it comes the Data-Link layer and very confused me. it says there:

> • Reliable delivery. When a link-layer protocol provides reliable delivery service, it
>   guarantees to move each network-layer datagram across the link without error.
>   Recall that certain transport-layer protocols (such as TCP) also provide a reliable
>   delivery service. Similar to a transport-layer reliable delivery service, a link-layer
>   reliable delivery service can be achieved with acknowledgments and retransmissions

in previous chapters of this book i learned about UDP/TCP, Stop & wait, Go-Back-N. what is the connection between these terms themsfelfs,  and how they refer to the data link layer? what is the meaning of "Recall that certain transport-layer protocols (such as TCP) **also** provide a reliable
delivery service." ?

I'd be happy if someone could clear the things I've mentioned above, and make all sense. thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a nice anwser to your question: http://superuser.com/questions/401935/difference-between-the-reliable-delivery-by-link-protocols-and-by-tcp. Let me quote: `Ensuring reliability over one hop and leaving remaining hops in the data path with unknown reliability would be beneficial if that hop was inherently more unreliable, e.g. a wireless link. ... Wireless ... can be very unreliable, and a reliable link-layer protocol could enhance (or at least not degrade) throughput of a mixed-wired-and-wireless network.`